# How to convert Matlab cell string array to .NET string array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, matlab

I have my cell array (89*1 cell) in Matlab that I want to convert into .Net string array (string[]). I'm using next code:

```
 b = NET.createArray('System.String',length(a));      
 b = NET.convertArray(a{1},'System.String');
```

In the result I catch next message: Conversion from 'cell' array type is not supported.

Comment: If i do: `a = {'hello', 'world'}; b = NET.createArray('System.String',length(a));b = NET.convertArray(a{1},'System.String');` I get the error: **Conversion from 'char' array type is not supported.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [net.convertArray](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/net.convertarray.html) is for converting *numeric* data.

This seems to what you want:

```
a = {'hello', 'world'};
b = NET.createArray('System.String', numel(a))
for i = 1:numel(a)
    b(i) = a{i};
end
```

I don't know if there is a faster/easier way.